# Getting Exception "not all code path return a value"

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have a method which updates a MySQL table using a query. I'm using a MS Visual Studio and phpmyadmin as the SQL client.

Method:

```
public static Member updateMember(string un, string pass, string name, string surname,                 string mf, string dob, string add, string phone, string email)
    {




        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        MySqlCommand cmd;

        string query = "UPDATE MEMBER SET Name='" + un + "', Surname='" + surname + "',      MF='" + mf + "', DOB='" + dob + "', Address='" + add + "', PhoneNo='" + phone + "', EMail='" + email + "', UserName='" + un + "', Password='" + pass + "' ";


        tr y
        {


            connection.Open();
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is what's happening. I'm storing some values from TextBoxes in a form in string variables. Then I'm sending those string variables to this method. I want that this method grabs my string variables and update my SQL table with the values of my variables.

I'm getting an error not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Just for future reference this is a build error not an exception. Your title is a little misleading

Comment: Also your catch block is redundant, it can be taken out to leave you with just keep the try/finally

Comment: Please look up the use of bind parameters and `using` blocks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method is not returning anything, You need to return the Member Object.

If you do not need to return anything , just change your Method Signature like this,

```
public static Void updateMember(string un, string pass, string name, string surname,string mf, string dob, string add, string phone, string email)
```

Comment: Alternatively OP could use return type `bool` to know whether row updated or not. `return true` when `ExecuteNonQuery` return `>0`, otherwise `return false`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the post of @Sajeetharan is that you return the value of your **ExecuteNonQuery** call

```
connection.Open();
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = query;
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course you also have to return something at the end of your method (after the **finally** block).

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, we need't return object like `Member` when update/insert or delete. We should return just a **Boolean** flag or return **Nothing**.

If you return flag, you should set it as result of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0` and also in `Catch` brand.

If you return nothing, just modify your method to

```
public static void updateMember(...)
{
    ....
}
```